# How to calculate size of all Azure Storage Tables from a Subscription using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell, azure-tablequery

How to calculate size of all Azure Storage Tables from a Subscription using Powershell.

I tried to search online if there is any direct way of querying table sizes but looks like there isn't. 
Can you someone please give me a working model of calculating a Azure Storage Table size.

Please.

```html
FOREACH ($SubscriptionID in $Subscriptions) { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Working on $N. $SubscriptionID" 

    $StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
    FOREACH ($StorageAccount in $StorageAccounts) {
            $StorageAccountName = $StorageAccount.StorageAccountName
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Working on $StorageAccountName"

            $AllTables = Get-AzStorageTable -Context $StorageAccount.Context
            FOREACH ($TableName in $AllTables) {
                
                $Name = $TableName.Name
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Working on $StorageAccountName,$Name"
                Get-AzStorageTable –Name $TableName.Name –Context $StorageAccount.Context
                
                }             
            }
            $N = $N+1
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the size of all Azure Storage Tables, but the minimum granularity could just be all the tables in a storage account, not a specific table.

Try the command as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
foreach($item in $StorageAccounts){
    $id = $item.Id+"/tableServices/default"
    $name = $item.StorageAccountName
    $metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $id -MetricName "TableCapacity" -WarningAction Ignore
    $data = $metric.Data.Average/1024/1024
    Write-Output "Tables in $name : $data MB"
}
```

[image]

---

**Besides**, looks you want to use the command in several subscriptions, if so, I think you need to run [`Set-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-2.8.0) to set the subscription before running the command above.

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Comment: You are the best. 
It worked like a charm. I'll now start working on piping the result Subscription and Per Storage Account into our SQL DB.